# Insert into mysql database not working no errors given

Tags: php, mysql

The retrieval of the bans works, however when i try to input a new ban into the database nothing happens.  No errors or anything.

```
function get_mysql() {
    $mysql = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "table");

    if ($mysql->connect_error) {
        die($mysql->connect_error);
    }

    return $mysql;
}

//ban stuff
    //bans the player given a uuid, moderator, an Expiration date and a reason
    function ban($uuid, $moderator, $expiration, $reason) {
        get_mysql()->query("INSERT INTO banLogger (UUID, Moderator, Expiration, Reason) values ('$uuid', '$moderator', '$expiration', '$reason'");
    }

    //returns all the bans for a specific player
    function get_ban_by_player($uuid) {
        return get_mysql()->query("SELECT * FROM banLogger where UUID = '$uuid'")->fetch_assoc();
    }

    //returns all the bans
    function get_all_bans() {
        return get_mysql()->query("SELECT * FROM banLogger")->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

Running the actual code

```
ban('051a6abd-37a9-48bd-a815-55aab7290206', 'mod', '2015-02-04 00:00:00',     'testing');
```

[image: MySQL structure]

Comment: echo your insert query and then try to run in the phpmyadmin or your mysql client to verify if works

Comment: function ban($uuid, $moderator, $expiration, $reason) {
        echo "INSERT INTO banLogger (UUID, Moderator, Expiration, Reason) values ('$uuid', '$moderator', '$expiration', '$reason'";
    }

Comment: yes the code worked successfullly when run through the sql.

Comment: 1- Check your table structure
2- Add clear values

Comment: 1) edited post to show structure.  2) what do you mean by add clear values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing parenthesis missing from the values of your insert query, it should be :

`"INSERT INTO banLogger (UUID, Moderator, Expiration, Reason) values ('$uuid', '$moderator', '$expiration', '$reason')"`